# About the PK in Azure Table Storage?

Tags: c#, azure-table-storage

Can I use guid as a PK (PartitionKey) in Azure Table Storage? Or should I use ordered strings?

```
PartitionKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N").ToLower();
```

or

```
PartitionKey = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString();
```

Which key is better for performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would depend on your access pattern, but in general, using ordered list is an example of append only pattern that does not work well with high scale scenarios and is discouraged. You can learn more about good way to design azure tables from azure storage blog link [How to get most out of Windows Azure Tables](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/11/06/how-to-get-most-out-of-windows-azure-tables.aspx)